# Cypress integration with Qmetry

Tags: github, cypress

So i was wondering if anyone has integrated cypress with qmetry.
We have integrated cypress with github actions so if not cypress with qmetry maybe the results from github actions to qmetry?

Comment: What is precisely the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following blogs to upload Cypress test results to QMetry. Cypress can generate the test results in JUnit format which can be further imported to QTM4J :

QMetry Test Management - Standalone : [Here are the steps](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QPro/pages/3090808855/How+to+import+Cypress+automation+results+into+QMetry+QTM/)

QMetry Test Management for Jira - QTM4J : [Here are the steps](https://qmetrysupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/QTM4J/pages/3001548847/How+to+integrate+Cypress+results+with+QTM4J/)

For further questions reach out to QMetry Support at qtmprofessional@qmetrysupport.atlassian.net with all the details and your shall receive required assistance.